# Core Data - query to-many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data model that look something like this:

```
Author
======
- name
- bio

- books (to-many relationship)


Book
====
- title
- release date

- author (to-one relationship)
```

I present to the user a table view of authors each table cell represent an author and shows his `name` and the `title` of the latest book he wrote.

To show the list of authors I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the following `NSFetchRequest` :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Author"];
request.predicate = nil;
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
```

**My question is:**

How should I get the title of the latest book for each author? can I get that info in my original request or do I need to do some additional requests?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to execute another fetch request if you already have an `Author` managed object. Just create a sorted array from the `Author`'s `books` property. To accomplish this, you could use `NSSet`'s `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method and pass in a descriptor that sorts by release date.

Comment: that means that i'm loading all the author's books from the data base just to get the one of them.

Comment: @Eyal you're right. And that would be fine for one author, but not for every author in the table view. So I would use Groenewald's answer. My answer is more pedagogical than pragmatic.

Answer (score 0):

To get it as part of the same request you could include an attribute on the `Author` object that stores the latest book

```
Author
======
- name
- bio
- latestBook

- books (to-many relationship)
```

Then to get the details simply use `author.latestBook.title`

You would also need to set the `latestBook` attribute when you add the latest book to the `books` attribute.

Alternately it could be a transient attribute that you calculate from the set of books based on the latest `releaseDate`.